# not able to connect using jaxl xmpp framework

Tags: php, xmpp, jaxl

i am trying to connect with openfire server using `JAXL XMPP Library` for PHP but i am falling into infinite loop, i have used strophe i am able to connect using that but not in PHP

here is my code

```
$client = new JAXL(array(
    'jid' => 'user1@mydomain.in',
    'pass' => 'pass@123',
   // 'host'=>'mydomain.in',
    //'port'=>'5222',
    'bosh_url' => 'http://rewire.in/http-bind',
    'log_level'=>JAXL_DEBUG,
    'log_path'=> './log/xmpp.txt',
   // 'auth_type'=>'DIGEST-MD5'
));
```

here is my log

```
jaxl:188 - 2014-03-26 16:40:58 - created pid file C:\Apache24\htdocs\mypro\JAXL/.jaxl/run/jaxl_16028.pid
jaxl_exception:66 - 2014-03-26 16:40:58 - error handler called with 8, Undefined index: host, C:\Apache24\htdocs\mypro\JAXL\jaxl.php, 197
jaxl_exception:66 - 2014-03-26 16:40:58 - error handler called with 8, Undefined index: port, C:\Apache24\htdocs\mypro\JAXL\jaxl.php, 197
jaxl:200 - 2014-03-26 16:40:58 - dns srv lookup for mydomain.in
jaxl:208 - 2014-03-26 16:40:58 - including bosh xep
jaxl_exception:66 - 2014-03-26 16:40:58 - error handler called with 8, Undefined index: resource, C:\Apache24\htdocs\mypro\JAXL\jaxl.php, 223
jaxl_exception:66 - 2014-03-26 16:40:58 - error handler called with 8, Undefined index: force_tls, C:\Apache24\htdocs\mypro\JAXL\jaxl.php, 224
jaxl_exception:66 - 2014-03-26 16:40:58 - error handler called with 8, Undefined index: bosh_rid, C:\Apache24\htdocs\mypro\JAXL\xep\xep_0206.php, 193
jaxl_exception:66 - 2014-03-26 16:40:58 - error handler called with 8, Undefined index: bosh_hold, C:\Apache24\htdocs\mypro\JAXL\xep\xep_0206.php, 194
jaxl_exception:66 - 2014-03-26 16:40:58 - error handler called with 8, Undefined index: bosh_wait, C:\Apache24\htdocs\mypro\JAXL\xep\xep_0206.php, 195
jaxl_fsm:61 - 2014-03-26 16:40:58 - calling state handler 'setup' for incoming event 'start_cb'
xep_0114:68 - 2014-03-26 16:40:58 - starting component handshake
jaxl_exception:66 - 2014-03-26 16:40:58 - error handler called with 8, Undefined index: id, C:\Apache24\htdocs\mypro\JAXL\xmpp\xmpp_stanza.php, 81
xep_0206:109 - 2014-03-26 16:40:58 - posting to http://mydomain.in/http-bind body <body sid="" rid="3285" xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind"><handshake>ba97b1cf397425a852d1316d10787b1d97b5bc85</handshake></body>
jaxl_fsm:71 - 2014-03-26 16:40:58 - current state 'wait_for_stream_features'
xep_0206:109 - 2014-03-26 16:40:58 - posting to http://mydomain.in/http-bind body <body xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind" content="text/xml; charset=utf-8" to="mydomain.in" route="xmpp:mydomain.in:5222" secure="true" xml:lang="en" xmpp:version="1.0" xmlns:xmpp="urn:xmpp:xbosh" hold="1" wait="30" rid="3285" ver="1.10" from="user1@mydomain.in"></body>
xep_0206:132 - 2014-03-26 16:40:58 - recving for 3285
xep_0206:132 - 2014-03-26 16:40:58 - recving for 3285
xep_0206:132 - 2014-03-26 16:40:58 - recving for 3285
xep_0206:132 - 2014-03-26 16:40:58 - recving for 3285
xep_0206:132 - 2014-03-26 16:40:58 - recving for 3285
xep_0206:132 - 2014-03-26 16:40:58 - recving for 3285
xep_0206:132 - 2014-03-26 16:40:58 - recving for 3285
xep_0206:132 - 2014-03-26 16:40:58 - recving for 3285
```

Answer (score 2):

I am also faced the same issue when integrating JAXL in my project. Looking for answers for the past 2 to 3 weeks and ends up with the perfect solution.

I have added my answer in the question which i have added earlier.
[Openfire http prebinding with JAXL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26654397/openfire-http-prebinding-with-jaxl/26795193#26795193)

Hope this could help.